# How can i connect to Teradata using python. I am using teradatasql package but getting error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, teradata

I am trying to connect to teradata using teradatasql module. But getting connection refused error . I am using below codes for same. Is there any way to connect to teradata for same.

```
connection = td.connect(host="abc.**.**.com", user="user_id", password="**********")
```

Error :

```
teradatasql.OperationalError: [Version 17.0.0.2] [Session 0] [Teradata SQL Driver] Failed to         connect to abc.**.**.com
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeDriverError TeradataConnection.go:1101
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.newTeradataConnection TeradataConnection.go:164
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataDriver).Open TeradataDriver.go:32
 at database/sql.dsnConnector.Connect sql.go:600
 at database/sql.(*DB).conn sql.go:1103
 at database/sql.(*DB).Conn sql.go:1619
 at main.goCreateConnection goside.go:275
 at main._cgoexpwrap_212fad278f55_goCreateConnection _cgo_gotypes.go:240
 at runtime.call64 asm_amd64.s:574
 at runtime.cgocallbackg1 cgocall.go:316
 at runtime.cgocallbackg cgocall.go:194
 at runtime.cgocallback_gofunc asm_amd64.s:826
 at runtime.goexit asm_amd64.s:2361
 Caused by dial tcp 14.167.77.56:775: connect: connection refused
```

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you are not reaching an active Teradata node. Perhaps it's a DNS issue. Does it work if you use the IP address in place of a hostname?

Answer (score 0):

The code should be,

```
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd
with teradatasql.connect(host='your_host_name', user='your_user_name', password='*******', logmech = "LDAP", encryptdata='true') as connect:  
  data = pd.read_sql(query, connect)
print(data.head())
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd
with teradatasql.connect(host='your_host_name', user='your_user_name', password='*******') as connect:
   data = pd.read_sql('select * from your_table_name;', connect)
print(data.head())
```

Try  above line of code, this might help you.